# GoogleMaps and OnMyLocationChangeListener, am i right?

Tags: android, google-maps, geopositioning

Ok, Hello everyone (sorry for my English). I have a task to make some good location service. I use google and stackoverflow , find a lot of tutorials, but i want to ask am i right? I have destination point and my current geo position. I draw route like this tutorial http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-draw-route-between-two-geo.html, and now i want to react if my current position changed, so i implement OnMyLoactionChangeListner, and now the question: if my position change i have to get new rout from url and redraw my polyline, or i can just make a marker and mark my new position above the old route polyline? what decision is right? Thanks for all

Comment: whats exactly you want to ask here? Have you tried some thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980279/how-to-check-if-my-current-location-is-on-the-route-that-i-draw-befor-and-if-no
look here please maybe you know am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I think that best would be to check if your current position is on the old route. If so, you could just shorten the first polyline. But if the position is outside of the route, you have to recalculate it.

Comment: That is what i cant find how "you could just shorten the first polyline"?

Comment: and one more question how i have to check if user location is on the old line?